# Sql querying Ids of a table inner joined with a 'list' table

Tags: sql, sqlite

In Sqlite I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Person" (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
"Age" INTEGER, "Email" TEXT)

CREATE TABLE "_Person_Name" (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Owner INTEGER NOT NULL, Name TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(Owner) REFERENCES Person(Id))
```

where the second table represents a list of strings for the name of a Person.

I would like to query Person.Id by matching names such that several conditions may match for in the same row *or* in different rows of _Person_Name.Name. For example, suppose Person.Id 1 has 2 associated rows _Person_Name.Name "John" and "Smith", both with _Person_Name.Owner=1. Then I'd like to have a query that returns exactly this Person.Id 1 based on searching for "John" and for "Smith". "John Wilson" or "Jonas Smith" should not be returned, but "John Theodore Smith" should be returned.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT Person.Id FROM Person 
INNER JOIN _Person_Name ON Person.Id = _Person_Name.Owner 
WHERE (Name LIKE 'John') AND (Name LIKE 'Smith');
```

But this doesn't work. It finds the person with each of the conditions separately, but the conjunction of both seems to apply to the same row only, so nothing is returned.

How can I search for both conditions such that they must both apply to the same person Id, but may match in different rows of the list table?

Edit: Here is an example of the schema with data. It's just an example, this is for an automated tool that deals with arbitrary schemas and associated 'list' tables.

```
Table Person
Id    Age    Email
==================
1      30    john@test.com
2      28    lucie@gmail.com
3      47    bob@gmail.com

Table _Person_Names
Id     Name   Owner (Foreign Key references Person.Id)
1      John   1
2      C.     1
3      Smith  1
4      Lucie  2
5      Smith  2
6      Bob    3
7      Smith  3
```

The query should return only Id 1, because only Person.Id 1 has both "John" and "Smith" in the table _Person_Names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is finding if there are 2 rows inside `_Person_Names` containing the values `John` and `Smith` in the column `Name` and having the same value in column `Owner`.  
This has nothing to do with the table `Person`. 
If 2 such rows can be found, then the value in column `Owner` is the `Id` in the table `Person`. Right? 
Check this code:

```
SELECT Owner FROM 
(SELECT pn.Owner AS Owner, pn.Name AS Name1, p.Name AS Name2 
FROM _Person_Names AS pn 
INNER JOIN _Person_Names AS p ON (pn.Owner = p.Owner) AND (Name1 <> Name2))
WHERE (Name1 = 'John') AND (Name2 = 'Smith')
```

Comment: I know, but that's not what I'm looking for at all. As I've stated, I do *not* want every name containing John OR Smith, I want to get only the Ids of persons whose name list contains both a "John" and a "Smith" row. Your query also returns "Lucie Smith", "John F Kennedy", etc. I'm only looking for "John C. Smith", "John Theodore Smith", "Bob John Smith Wilcrow", and so forth. (In case you wonder, this is for a tool that deals with arbitrary lists within arbitrary user-defined schemas in a non-Sql query language that is translated to the Sqlite backend.)

Comment: This doesn't work. Each part of the name is in a Name column in a row of its own in table _Person_Name where the Owner field has the Person.Id of table Person as Owner.

Comment: You mean that John and Smith are in different rows?

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. I didn't know that you can inner join the same table to itself, but with the renaming it makes sense.  I will test your solution.

Comment: Of course you can join a table to itself and it's a very common practice.

Answer (score 0):

Using an AND operator in WHERE clause is not retrieving the correct result. You should use an OR operator

**Edited part starts here**

```
select Person.ID, Dusra_table.name
    from person, dusra_table
where Person.ID = Dusra_Table.Owner
    and (Dusra_Table.Name = 'John'
            OR  Dusra_Table.Name = 'Smith'
      )
    and Person.ID = ANY(Select Dusra_Table.Owner from Dusra_table where Name = 'John');
```

Dusra_Table is _Person_Names table

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, please see my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first, middle, and last names are all in the same column, you could also try modifying your WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE Name LIKE 'John % Smith'
```

Same result as forpas and Namandeep_Kaur methods just less bulky

Comment: No, they are not in the same column - they *may* be, but do not need to be. I'll try to update my question to make this more clear.